# UPDATE column table postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update a column table in postgres but I don't know how to do this...

I have a table with 3 columns like nickname, color and json which is a string this one has an object like

```
{"value1":"answer1", "value2":"answer2" }
```

At the column with the json I want to add nickname and color values...

Like this:

```
 {"value1":"answer1", "value2":"answer2", "nickname":"name1", "color":"red" }
```

How can I do this update?

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using, and will you be performing this update from Hibernate/JPA?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using postgresSQL 9.4 and yes it will be performing to JPA

Comment: Load the entity, modify it. Just like you would do with any other entity and any other column. The fact that is contains a JSON string doesn't change anything. A String is a String is a String.

Comment: You want to add the color and nickname of the other columns or different ones?

Comment: @JBNizet can you show me a simple example, please?

Comment: `MyEntity e = entityManager.findMyEntity.class, theId); e.setJson(newJsonString);`

Comment: @stickybit I want to add nickname and color of the same row

Comment: @JBNizet How can I do it using only postgres language?

Comment: So you don't want to use JPA anymore? What changed in the last 12 minutes?

Comment: @JBNizet Maybe countdown to New Year's day?

Comment: @JBNizet I see that I can run the script directly in my databse

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this from Postgres, then you may try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '{"value1":"answer1", "value2":"answer2"}'::json AS col
)

UPDATE cte
SET col = REGEXP_REPLACE(col::text,
                         '\}$',
                         ', "nickname":"name1", "color":"red"}')::json;


{"value1":"answer1", "value2":"answer2", "nickname":"name1", "color":"red"}
```

This approach uses direct string manipulation to find the end of the JSON string, and then to insert the new key value pairs.

If you were using Postgres 9.5 or later, you might be to use the merge `||` operator to add the new JSON content.  Postgres' support for JSON manipulation has gotten better in recent versions, but version 9.4 does not offer much.

Also, if you could handle this from your Hibernate/JPA layer, it might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the existing columns of the table, you could use `json_build_object`.

```
UPDATE t 
    SET    json_col = ( replace(json_col :: text, '}', ',') 
            || replace(Json_build_object ('nickname', nickname, 
                 'color', color) :: text,'{', '' ) ) :: json ;
```

The `replace()` statements help in shaping the `json` string. Note that here I have considered your string to be a simple json string ( without nested arrays/jsons).

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=b2c6b02dc420335aa3c548c1daf46f49)

Comment: how can i remove the spaces between  ":" because it is like "nickname" : " value" ??

Comment: @t9217 : That's a different problem unrelated to this. Try using another `replace` or  consider asking a new question.

Comment: @t9217 You probably _don't_ even need to remove the spaces, because whatever is parsing your JSON content won't mind that they are there.